# Firebase: What's the meaning of color rows of realtime database row

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I'm trying to upload Qt's log to firebase.
Here is saved file's logs.

```
❯ cat *.log
2019:04:01 17:51:23.831 [Info] "FireRest version_name:0.1" [../LoginApp/mainwindow.cpp:13, MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *)]

2019:04:01 17:51:27.417 [Debug] Construct SignUpDialog [../LoginApp/signupdialog.cpp:16, SignUpDialog::SignUpDialog(QWidget *)]
```

My uploading code is at below.

```
    QFile *file = FireRest::getLogFile();

    if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "warning", file->errorString());
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(file);

    while(!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        uploadLog(line);
    }
```

I'm using Firebase's REST API with `put`.

But, uploaded data is deleted immediately without any delete operation.

First picture is on uploading.
[image]

this picture is after uploaded.   red colored items were disappeared.

[image]

What stands for these yellow, green, red color for items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors in the Firebase Realtime Database console have the following meaning:

- Red means that the node is being deleted from the database.
- Green means that the node is being added to the database.
- Yellow means that the node is being updated in the database.

If you've used the Firebase API before, you might recognize these as the `child_removed`, `child_added`, and `child_changed` events.

From experience, I'd say that your first screenshot corresponds to code that performs a `set(...)` operation of a child under `/devices/ered34wa/logs`. The operation writes the new child, but removes the existing child nodes.