# How to save data to Firebase RealTime Database in iOS?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As you can see in the picture below, every time I want to save data to the Firebase RealTime Database, I get these red "alerts" and the data won't be saved.

Initially, I thought it was an error of Authentication, but then I configured that too and still can't save data, although I can read it.

Do you know a way to resolve it? Or am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks for your answers :)

[image: Error saving data]

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452665/firebase-whats-the-meaning-of-color-rows-of-realtime-database-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was an authentication problem, the console would never show the data to begin with.

More likely you have another piece of code somewhere in your app (or in a backend process) that is listening to this same data, and writing back to the same location when it gets called.

Comment: Yes, it was because I was using .observe and not .getData. Thanks a lot :)